# Неоднозначное (ромбовидное) наследование

Tags: c++

**Доброго времени суток!**

Вопрос у меня, опять же, чисто академического характера, возник в результате более углубленного изучения "нутра" С++.

Допустим, где-то в заголовочном файле имеется связка классов такого вида:

```
class Base{ public: Base(){ std::cout<<"Create!"<<endl; } };
class Sub1 : public virtual Base{};
class Sub2 : public Base{};
class Multi : public Sub1, public Sub2{} ;
```

Здесь, как вы можете наблюдать, имеется ни что иное, как ромбовидное наследование.

Далее вызываем конструктор класса `Multi`:

```
int main()
{
    Multi m;
    return 0;
}
```

**Вывод:**

```
Create!
Create!
```

Едем дальше...если я специфицирую и класс Sub2, как виртуальный, то вывод будет иным, **а именно**:

```
Create!
```

Было бы очень хорошо, если бы вы прояснили, откуда именно происходит второй раз  вызов конструктора.

**Спасибо!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если я все правильно помню, то при ромбовидном наследовании класс Multi будет иметь две копии Base. Но если сделать наследование виртуальным, то копия будет одна.
Именно по этой причине то два раза выводится, то один.

**UPD:**
Странный, синтетический пример, но может кому  то он сэкономит время.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    int k;
    Base() {
        std::cout<<"Create!"<<std::endl;
        k = 0;
    }
    ~Base() {
        std::cout << "Delete " << k << std::endl;
    }
};

class Sub1 : public virtual Base {};
class Sub2 : public Base {};
class Sub3 : public virtual Base {};
class Sub4 : public Base {};
class Multi : public Sub1, public Sub2, public Sub3, public Sub4 {
    public:
        Multi() {
            if (Sub1::k == 0)
                Sub1::k = 1; 
            else 
                std::cout << " try init 1, but was init by " << Sub1::k << std::endl;
            if (Sub2::k == 0)
                Sub2::k = 2; 
            else 
                std::cout << " try init 2, but was init by " << Sub2::k << std::endl;
            if (Sub3::k == 0)
                Sub3::k = 3; 
            else 
                std::cout << " try init 3, but was init by " << Sub3::k << std::endl;
            if (Sub4::k == 0)
                Sub4::k = 4; 
            else 
                std::cout << " try init 4, but was init by " << Sub4::k << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Multi m;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Create!
Create!
Create!
 try init 3, but was init by 1
Delete 4
Delete 2
Delete 1
```

Для понимания, нужно знать, что `Sub1::k` это специальная форма, что бы обратиться к правильной ветке в ромбовидном наследовании (со словом специально я конечно погорячился - оно работает и в других наследованиях:) ).
Как видно, в выводе деструктора нет нулей, поэтому инициализировались точно все копии `Base`. Но как видно, одна копия (номер 3) не была инициализирована повторно.
Деструкторы обычно вызываются в обратном порядке.

Comment: А что значит виртуальное наследование?!

Comment: Ну, насколько мне известно, спецификатор virtual в ромбовидном наследовании как раз и служит для того, чтобы компилятор выбрал лишь один класс из двух, от которого будет происходить реальное наследование для класса Multi. Если это правда так, то в итоге класс Multi отнаследуется лишь от одного из двух классов. Если же оба класса Sub* пометить, как виртуальные, то компилятор "сольет" их в один. И опять же в итоге будет один вызов конструктора!

Comment: @gecube [подсказка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)
@Asen
Если при ромбовидном наследовании часть виртуальных, а часть - нет, то будет веселее. Для тех, кто виртуальный, будет создан один объект, для всех остальных будут созданны персональные копии.

Comment: @KoVadim, а как это "персональные копии"? И если это не так:

     Это не так, если один виртуальный, а один нет.

то как же тогда происходит?  Спасибо.

Comment: Это легче понять, если бы у нас было не два класса посредине (Sub1 и Sub2), а больше. Пусть будет 10. И класс Multi будет наследоваться от них всех. При этом пять наследований будут виртуальными(для Sub1 .. Sub5), а следующие пять (для Sub6 .. Sub10)- нет. Тогда будет создано 6 копий Base. Один экземпляр для Sub1 .. Sub5 и по персональному экземпляру для Sub6 .. Sub10.

Comment: @KoVadim, вот теперь все сразу стало ясно из вашего умного примера! Большое спасибо вам)

Comment: Как всегда, наследование порождает больше проблем, чем решает... Пичалька =( Ведь по сути наследование = включение в derived-класс base-класса.

И, что это получается, лучше всегда использовать виртуальное наследование вместо обычного!?!?!?

Comment: По поводу множественного наследования и связанных с ним проблем лучше всего написано у Мейерса. В общем мораль: лучше в С++ им не пользоваться.

Comment: Правильно мораль звучит иначе: понимаешь - пользуйся, не понимаешь - не пользуйся, серебряной пули - нет.

Comment: @mikillskegg, да уж, по большому счету, думаю, 99% задач, связанных с проектированием приложения можно решить без множественного наследования, но ведь, бывают и задачи сложности оставшегося 1%...